# Как корректно записать циклы в HTML для правильного вывода данных в table из списка содержащего кортежи

Tags: html, django, циклы, for, table

Есть такой список состоящий из кортежей:

```
*Список содержащий кортежи*
result = [(1, 'ivan', 36), (2, 'oleg', 31), (3, 'dima', 27)].

# ---------------------
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
    </tr
      {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.1 }}</td>    # -- > как возможно заменить эти три строки циклом/перебрать -
            <td>{{ user.2 }}</td>    #      - чтобы явно не указывать цифры 0, 1, 2      
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итерацию кортежей можно производить с помощью того же for loop, т.е. Ваш код будет:

```
    *Список содержащий кортежи*
    result = [(1, 'ivan', 36), (2, 'oleg', 31), (3, 'dima', 27)].
    
    # ---------------------
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        </tr
          {% for user in users %}
            <tr>
                {% for item in user %}
                      <td>{{ item }}</td>   
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Вот Cпасибо вам, вот вы --> умный человек :)